# How to reRequest permission for showing notifications in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: javascript, firebase, permissions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing the push notifications for web app with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

After the first run I got request notification promt because of this code:

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging
        .requestPermission()
        ..........
```

I have granted the permission, but now when I visit this page I didn't ever see the request for permission promt because I already granted the permission while the first run. How can I unsubscribe my device to see permission requests again?

Comment: In desktop/Android Chrome, at least, you can click the lock next to the URL, go to "Site Settings", and then change the "Notifications" setting.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh, yes I read about this. I thought it is possible to do it programmatically. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See:

- https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=0&hl=en
- chrome://settings/content/notifications
- https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-messaging
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/notification/requestPermission

> Deprecated requestPermission(). Use the native browser API Notification.requestPermission() instead.

If firebase version is newer 6.0.4 then you should use `Notification.requestPermission()`.

Comment: I thought it is possible to do it inside my script. But thank you, you helped me to solve the problem.